# How to perform Cross Origin request with TinCan.js

Tags: tin-can-api

I have an LRS set up on scorm cloud, and I'm setting up an LRS object as follows using `tincan-min.js`:

```
lrs = new TinCan.LRS(
    {
        endpoint: "https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/xxxxxxxxxx/",
        username: "me@example.com",
        password: "mypassword",
        allowFail: false
    }
);
```

I can send and retrieve statements from localhost using:

```
lrs.saveStatement(
    statement, { 
       // error logging
    });
```

However, when I run this in a course, I get a Cross Origin Request failure (because of the Same Origin Policy). I'm not sure what to do to fix this - is there something I can modify when setting up the `lrs` object or sending the statement?

Comment: TinCanJS has built in support for CORS and it should just work. What browser? Where is the content hosted cause it seems like it shouldn't even be a CORS request? What is the exact message in the console and/or is the OPTIONS request happening and working? Send a message to support@scorm.com for direct help with Cloud.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was accidentally unloading the script before the xhr got a response - d'oh! Firefox returned an error message about it being a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian pointed out, this functionality is built in and no extra work is needed.